# TypeError: theme.spacing is not a function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on react app and using material-ui v5 and I'm stuck on this error
theme.spacing is not working.

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import React from "react";
import Drawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@mui/material/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import { AddCircleOutlineOutlined, SubjectOutlined } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
  return {
    page: {
      background: "#f9f9f9",
      width: "100%",
      padding: theme.spacing(3),
    },
    drawer: {
      width: drawerWidth,
    },
    drawerPaper: {
      width: drawerWidth,
    },
    root: {
      display: "flex",
    },
    active: {
      background: "#f4f4f4 !important",
    },
  };
});

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();

  const menuItems = [
    {
      text: "My Notes",
      icon: <SubjectOutlined color="secondary" />,
      path: "/",
    },
    {
      text: "Create Note",
      icon: <AddCircleOutlineOutlined color="secondary" />,
      path: "/create",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      
      <div className={classes.page}>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

on line no. 19 that is "padding: theme.spacing(3)" it is showing error on my browser

> TypeError: theme.spacing is not a function

Comment: Are you using a custom theme in your provider?

Comment: @NearHuscarl no it didn't work either but it does work when I import in @mui/styles. Still thank you it helped me.

Answer (score 2):

**This is not working because you have to type your Theme**

1. import the Theme

   ```
   import { Theme } from '@mui/material'
   ```
2. Now type it:

   ```
   const useStyles=makeStyles((theme:Theme)=>({

       root:{
           background: 'black',
           padding:theme.spacing(3),
       }

   }))
   ```

I was facing the exact same problem and this worked for me.

Comment: I get this error with `Theme` - "Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8010)"

Answer (score 1):

How do you create the theme, did you made with createTheme? You need to pass the provider in the root of your application. Try import like this.

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles
```

Then define all your global styles for your application and then make, for example, this.

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
<ThemeProvider theme={yourtheme}><App/></ThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your import is wrong ? Try this

```
import {makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
```

Comment: its not working either 
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles"; is the correct way in v5